# ¿Como saber en que momento se ejecutó un trigger en base de datos MySql?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Me gustaría saber los triggers que se han ejecutado en tal hora y los cambios de una columna especifica.

Debido que por alguna razón extraña, se actualiza un campo de una tabla a valor cero. Esto se debe a unos triggers que existe en la base de datos, lo cual son muchísimos.

Necesito saber que trigger se ejecutó, el valor de la columna especifica, idealmente con la hora incluida. Por ejemplo, ando buscando cuando se modifico la columna comprado de una tabla que se llama presupuestosa:

```
Nombre trigger| comprado |Tabla         | hora
---------------------------------------------
triggres1     | 0        |presupuestosa |2019-01-24
triggres2     | null     |presupuestosa |2019-01-24
triggres1     | 0        |presupuestosa |2019-01-25
triggres3     | null     |presupuestosa |2019-01-26
```

Quizas, la idea es crear alguna tabla que registre esos valores de ejemplo que mostre. O quizas exista alguna otra forma de saberlo.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, se le agradece.
Desde ya, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola considera activar el log general de mysql. Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

Ingresar con el usuario administrador por consola:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Mediante SET GLOBAL habilitar el general log:

```
mysql> set global general_log=1;
```

Mediante SET SESSION habilitar el log de sql:

```
mysql> set session sql_log_off=1;
```

Generalmente el log lo deja en la siguiente ubicación:

> XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/MacBook-Pro-de-Mac.log

Bueno si estás utilizando XAMPP y OS X, es posible que cambie dependiendo del sistema operativo y si estas utilizando algún paquete como XAMPP. Esto lo puedes consultar en Internet.

También puedes hacer esta consulta por consola y te mostrar la ubicación y el nombre del archivo log.

```
mysql> show variables like 'general_log%';
+------------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                    |
+------------------+--------------------------+
| general_log      | OFF                      | 
| general_log_file | /var/log/mysql/query.log | 
+------------------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Te muestra algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrias buscar en este log el query que esta actualizando los datos.

Más información aquí:

http://systemadmin.es/2012/09/query-log-de-mysql-general-log

Recuerda desactivarlo después que termines porque esto causa lentitud en la base de datos.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la informacion de los triggers mediante la tabla del sistema triggers

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.triggers
```

o tambien con el siguiente query

```
SHOW TRIGGERS
```

Si quieres filtrar por cual trigger solo tienes que agregarle un WHERE a la consulta

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.triggers 
WHERE TRIGGER_NAME='Nombre'
```

Y al segundo con un LIKE

```
SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'Nombre'
```